# Are there any well known algorithms for synthetic handwriting?

Tags: ds.algorithms, ai.artificial-intel

Please excuse if this is too practical. I decided it was not technical enough for stack overflow and probably suitable for here.

Given a set of letters, A-Z, what is the best scalable way to represent them in some form of synthetic handwriting.

I define synthetic handwriting to be a set of paths drawn on a canvas by a cursor, guided by the machine as if a human were writing with a pen.

The reason I am asking this is because I'm writing black box tests for one of my projects and want to fill up a database with fake signatures. Of course, I am also interested in the algorithms.

My first inclination is to take A-Z and draw paths myself, perhaps as SVGs and use those, but I think there must be some best way to do this so I am asking here.

I will post my research as I find information, as well.

EDIT:

This one looks nice: https://docs.google.com/open?id=1Hu2-dkqFDTBkDirjdemfBqln4-dS4I5QfYTF-6o-DsaxdCbkDDJ4LH1gkjal

Style-preserving English handwriting synthesis
Zhouchen Lin a,∗ , Liang Wan b
a Microsoft Research, Asia, Zhichun Road #49, Haidian District, Beijing 100080, PR China

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to generate the signatures by hand, scan them in, and use them that way. This would be quicker, unless you can find an off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: I did find this, though: [Synthetic Generation of Handwritten Signatures Based on Spectral Analysis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=generating%20handwritten%20signatures&source=web&cd=12&ved=0CC4QFjABOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.186.1480%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=mSzqTt-uEsmc-wa_q5SlCQ&usg=AFQjCNHIs0aTdgreDdIU28cHoYJ71qs5Hw&sig2=BizyDwVoOop3LY-GtM5UMA). Perhaps they have software available.

Comment: @DaveClarke I agree that it would be easier/faster to just do them by hand, but I'm not on the clock or anything right now. I'm dabbling for fun and looking to make something ridiculous/impressive. I might draw out each A-Z letter and make them re-usable, even if it doesn't look cursive.

Comment: Isn't this out of scope ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat: Looks like. However, it's a worthwhile discussion and should eventually find a suitable/ appropriate site.

Comment: @Kris, cstheory is a Q&A site and not for discussions.

Comment: Tom, you might want to try the AI Q&A sites linked in the [faq].